# How to find a substring position and length from a txt file

Tags: c#, .net, text, substring

I have a text file that contains information that I can use in order to get 
a string.substring(position,length).

```
// this is a sample data 
String Data = "NAMENAMENAMENAMENAMENAMENAMEAGE119861126"
```

.txt file that contains the position and length

```
    Element   Length    Position
    Name       30       1
    Age         2       31
    ID          1       33
    DOB         2       34
```

What I wanted to do is loop thru the rules from the text file and get a substring of 
the string Data.

Comment: you saved the length and position values in a random txt file?

Comment: This is more a "Here is my assignment, can you do it for me" question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `File.ReadLines` and `String.Split`, here is some LINQ-magic:

```
String Data = "NAMENAMENAMENAMENAMENAMENAMEAGE119861126";
var substringInfos = File.ReadLines("Path")
    .SkipWhile(l => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)).Skip(1) // skip empty lines and the header
    .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Where(split => split.Length == 3)
    .Select(split => new
    {
        Element = split[0],
        Length = int.Parse(split[1]),
        Position = int.Parse(split[2])
    });

foreach (var info in substringInfos)
{
    string substring = Data.Substring(info.Position, info.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Element: '{0}' Value: '{1}'", info.Element, substring);
}
```

Result:

```
Element: 'Name' Value: 'AMENAMENAMENAMENAMENAMENAMEAGE'
Element: 'Age'  Value: '11'
Element: 'ID'   Value: '9'
Element: 'DOB'  Value: '86'
```

Comment: can you explain to me the substringInfo variable how do you know where to split or do the skip?

Comment: @HXD: what part of the LINQ query don't you understand? The first skips all empty lines and the first line which is not empty which is the header. Then it splits every line by space or tab since your sample data seems to split by tab, but i wasn't sure if that's correct. Then i check if the string[] contains three elements, otherwise this line will be ignored. The three tokens are used to initialze an anonymous type. In the `foreach` the LINQ query is executed and the result is written to the console.